# init() methods are not working and works if I remove autocomplete block

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

init() methods are not working and works if I remove autocomplete block.

init methods contains some datatable.js initialization to table on page

[this is demo page](http://ris.sahyadritechnologies.com/profile)

note. Autocomplete is working well.
I could not find the problem.

```
<script>
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
});


//  var oTable = null;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    App.init();
    PortletDraggable.init();
    FormFileUpload.init();
    EducationalQualification.init();
    WorkExperience.init();
    Supervisions.init();
    Awards.init();
    Publication.init();
});

    var tmpMem = 0; var tmpAward = 0; var tmpPub = 0;
    // Js For Autocomplete
    $('input[name=SearchUser]').autocomplete({
    //logic here
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle as an example?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined

}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
```

That could possibly be the cause.

You also have issues where you're missing a quote `"` in front of the URL in your script tags;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=/assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=/assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=/assets/plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks olimortimer, could you please help me to sort out the error.

Comment: I have added quotes in front of the URL at my localhost already.

Comment: You're trying to add the data to an autocomplete element, but it doesn't exist.  Should this be .autocomplete or #autocomplete ?

Comment: but autocomplete is working properly , its not hosted yet online.

Comment: if I call any method methodname() instead of PortletDraggable.init(), it works the exact way.

Comment: I have asked this many times on many forums but no one solve this, is it totally wrong.

Comment: All are not working and if I remove autocomplete all work properly.

Comment: If they work without the autocomplete function, then it must be something to do with that.  Try removing parts of the autocomplete function (ie, the .data() part that's erroring), and see if the init() functions start working then.